# XSLT - passing document as param to a template not working

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm putting together data from two different xml files with a xsl stylesheet.
When I'm in the main template that filters the correct DOM from the other xml file I want to pass that DOM to another template for getting only the needed informations back.
But here is the point where I stucked because it seems that I'm not able to pass a DOM structure with the "xsl:with-param". When I try the output in the sub template the passed param is empty.

```
<xsl:variable name="data" select="/entry/document('data.xml')/documents" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:param name="matchingNodes" select="$data/document[documentInfos/documentInfo[documentInfoField = '120']/content/value = current()/ARTICLE]"/>

    <xsl:if test="count($matchingNodes)">
        <xsl:call-template name="PRODUCT_NAME">
            <xsl:with-param name="matchingNodes" select="$matchingNodes"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="PRODUCT_NAME"/>
  <xsl:param name="matchingNodes"/> <-- this is empty
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

How can I get my filtered document in the template or is it even not possible?

**UPDATE**

The leading XML file is the second one. The first one is for checking if the article is actually in this to allow the transformation.

```
#First XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry>
  <documents>
    <document>
      <name>Product A</name>
      <id>100-123</id>
      <documentInfos>
        <documentInfo>
            <locales>[de]</locales>
            <content>
              <language>de</language>
              <value>100</value>
            </content>
          <documentInfoField type="">120</documentInfoField>
        </documentInfo>
      </documentInfos>
    </document>
    <document>
      <name>Product B</name>
      <id>200-124</id>
      <documentInfos>
        <documentInfo>
            <locales>[en]</locales>
            <content>
              <language>de</language>
              <value>210</value>
            </content>
          <documentInfoField type="">120</documentInfoField>
        </documentInfo>
      </documentInfos>
    </document>
  </documents>
</entry>

# Second XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TREE>
  <BLOCK>
    <STATUS>1</STATUS>
    <ARTICLE>100</ARTICLE>
  </BLOCK>
  <BLOCK>
    <STATUS>1</STATUS>
    <ARTICLE>200</ARTICLE>
  </BLOCK>
</TREE>
```

**UPDATE 2**

It is now working! I don't get it!?!
I can only get access to that passed param when I call it e.g. like that

```
<xsl:template name="PRODUCT_NAME"/>
  <xsl:param name="matchingNodes"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$matchingNodes"/>
</xsl:template>
```

But then there is a new problem.
I need to match only the product name inside that template and now I saw that I have to use the "match" argument in the template definition like this:

```
<xsl:template match="documentInformationEntry[documentInformationField = '100']/content[language = 'de']/value>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to evaluate this.
I'm using Oxygen as a tool to build the stylesheet. There is a selector on the top left that is saying Saxon-PE 9.8.0.12.
Is that the version?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. I wouldn't expect any weird issues from that engine. Are you sure that the PRODUCT_NAME template is being called? How are you observing that?

Comment: Yes I'm sure that it is called because I use break-points. And the debugger stopped inside that template and the variable in Oxygen shows me that it is empty. :-(

Comment: I guess I will stuck here.
It seems that xsl:with-param can only transfer values and not nodes. So I got a big problem because I've to find another solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207363/discussion-between-timo-klement-and-jlrishe).

Comment: *" It seems that xsl:with-param can only transfer values and not nodes."* No, that's certainly not true. If the parameter is empty, then you are not selecting any nodes when defining it. We might be able to point out the problem if we could see the input XML.

Comment: @michael.hor257k The `<xsl:if>` around the `<xsl:call-template>` suggests that it is not empty

Comment: @JLRishe Maybe, maybe not. I am not going to add anything without a [mcve].

Comment: I added a minimized structure of my files I'm working with.

Comment: @Timo.Klement Inside a `<xsl:template match="/">`, `current()/ARTICLE` would refer to a node that doesn't exist. `current()` would be the root of the XML document in that situation and its only child is `<TREE>`

Comment: The code you've shown looks fine. Your theory as to why it's not working looks wrong. The bug is probably in something you didn't show us because you didn't think it was relevant. This illustrates the importance of providing the famous "minumum reproducible example": something we can actually run and debug in our own space.

Comment: @MichaelKay You are totally right! I updated my original post on top.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems. First, your `$data` variable is empty. You can verify this by running the following test:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="data" select="document('data.xml')/documents" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <test>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$data"/>
    </test>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is empty, because the root element of `data.xml` is `entry`, not `documents`. And also because the data.xml is not a well-formed XML document (at least not the example you have posted here).

In addition, the expression selecting the `$matchingNodes` variable also selects nothing - at least not in the provided example. For example, the expression `current()/ARTICLE` will always be empty, because `ARTICLE` is not a child of the current `/` node. And the path to `value` is also wrong.

Unfortunately, I cannot fix this for you, because I don't know what the `data.xml` document actually looks like. Or what are you actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm totally sorry. You are right. I tried to shorten the data.xml that there is not so much information in it and messed up with two nodes and the article value. It is now fixed in the main thread and there is now only one match the first article.

The selecting $matchingNodes in the "count" expression is only used to determine if there is at least one.

Comment: I suggest you post a new question with your new problem. Hint: use a [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key) to get data from a cross-referenced node.